# Finding how much value needed to reach 100

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progress-bar

I am working on a progress bar in react, and I want to show how much experience points still needed to go up a level. For example, level 1 require to have points between 0 and 100, level two require to have between 100 and 200.

My Aim is to show progress bar scaled to a hundred and in the progress bar show the % of how much needed to reach 100 and go to level two and so on till level 10.

```
const experienceLevel = () => {
    console.log("DAMMMMSNN");
    console.log(userData.experience);
    // Level one - > to level two
    if (userData.experience >= 0 && userData.experience < 100) {
      return (
        <>
          <p className="experience__show--level"> Level 1: Novice </p>
          <small className="experience__show--level--coming">
            <i>You need {99 - userData.experience} points to reach level two</i>
          </small>
          <progress
            className="experience__progression-bar__bar"
            **value={userData.experience} // my issue in this place**
            max="99"
          ></progress>
        </>
      );
      // Level two - > to level three
    } else if (userData.experience >= 100 && userData.experience < 200) {
      return (
        <>
          <p>Level 2: Monk</p>
          <small className="experience__show--level--coming">
            <i>
              You need {199 - userData.experience} points to reach level three
            </i>
          </small>
          <progress
            className="experience__progression-bar__bar"
            value={199 - userData.experience}
            max="100"
          ></progress>
        </>
      );
```

The value in the progress bar should present how much progress is done to reach another level, even though the for example level 2 100 - 200 and the user should have experience points between 100 - 200, but in the progress bar I want to scale it to 100 and present it.
Example if the person have 180 experience points, and he is in level 2, he still need 20 points (which I want to present it in the progress bar).

Comment: I solved the issue guys.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, This solution is easy. First You have to divide the number with 100.
Then the dividend will be your level and the reminder will be the number how much he/she is near to the next level.

Comment: What i did also is {userData.experience - 100} and max="100"

Comment: Yeah that is also right, but you have to use more if else! and in my formula you can do it with only one if condition. If you find my answer valuable please give a upvote